# Agora RTM login getting a timeout error code 9?

Tags: swift, timeout, agora.io

I am trying to log users into RTM in Swift and keep running into a timeout error when trying to login to RTM. RTC works fine and my tokens from the token server come quick and are valid. What else could be causing this?

```
  self.rtmKit?.login(byToken: self.tempToken[1], user: self.userForRTM) { (error) in
        if error != .ok {
            print("Error logging in: ", error.rawValue)
        } else {
            self.rtmChannel = self.rtmKit?.createChannel(withId: self.userName, delegate: self) //This is the AgoraRtmChannelDelegate, which must be set to get messageReceived, memberLeft, and memberJoined callbacks.
            self.rtmChannel?.join(completion: { (error) in
                if error != .channelErrorOk {
                    print("Error joining channel: ", error.rawValue)
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be a firewall error, which I've seen only a couple of times.

Could you try leaving the wifi connection if you are on one, and also trying on wifi if you're not already?

---

Edit:

We have identified the issue as likely a problem with IPv6 compatibility. There is a temporary fix here:

https://github.com/AgoraIO/AgoraRTM_iOS/releases/tag/1.4.8-230

The fix will be included in our next RTM release.

Comment: Yes! It ended up working on other Wi-fi networks as well as LTE.

Comment: Ashton was this with an iPad or iPhone?

Comment: it was an iPhone

Comment: ah okay, we're noticing some issues on iPad only that seem very similar to this

Comment: seems like it's related to ipv6 networks, a fix is being worked on this week

Comment: @maxxfrazer I am encountering this exact same issue when my device only has a cellular connection to the internet (no WiFI, or WiFi interface is not routable). As soon as I switch to a routable SSID, I can login. Does Agora not work over a cellular connection? If so, I'm afraid it's useless for my application. Hoping there's a workaround!

iPhone 14 Pro Max | iOS 16.5.1 | Xcode 14.3  | AgoraRTM_iOS 1.5.1

Comment: @Reid that's odd, could you check if the network is ipv4, ipv6, or a combination of ipv4 and ipv6. There were some issues in that area before, but I thought they were all flushed out. hit me up on twitter (or x?) if you like, same username there.

Comment: @maxxfrazer I'm both happy and embarrassed to report that this turned out to be a  classic Layer 8 error. Specifically, cellular data was switched off in my device's settings. So yeah...that makes sense. I sure appreciate the prompt reply!

Comment: @maxxfrazer hi! I'm seeing this issue in the production logs while we are on v 1.5.1 (latest stable) - is the ipv6 fix there? should I be looking for another problem? thank

Comment: is your network ipv6 only, or combined ipv4+ipv6? same as my question given to Reid above.